# How do I resolve my expo client app on Android that stop working?

Tags: react-native, expo

How do I fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SYgO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to using the `tunnel` connection type, it seems like you are unable to connect to other devices on your network.

This is discussed in the "Create a new app" section of the documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/get-started/create-a-new-app/#opening-the-app-on-your-phonetablet

> **Is the app not loading on your device?**
>
> First, make sure that you are on the same wifi network on your computer and your device.
>
> If it still doesn't work, it may be due to the router configuration — this is common for public networks. You can work around this by choosing the "Tunnel" connection type in Expo Dev Tools, then scanning the QR code again.
>
> Using the "Tunnel" connection type will make app reloads
> considerably slower than on "LAN" or "Local", so it's best to avoid
> tunnel when possible. You may want to install a simulator/emulator to
> speed up development if "Tunnel" is required for accessing your
> machine from another device on your network.